# Answer without unlocking in android 5.0

Tags: lock-screens, calls, 5.0-lollipop, phone-app

I recently upgraded my nexus 4 to android 5.0 (Via OTA update).  Now, for some reason, when I get a phone call the screen is black and I have to

1. press the power button
2. ress/swipe the lock icon on the screen
3. enter my password
4. swipe right to answer my call.

Before (android 4.4) all I had to do was slide to answer.  How can I get the old functionality back?

Comment: Lots of people experiencing problems with Lollipop on Nexus have found that a factory reset fixes them. You might try this too.

Comment: oddly my phone crashed, then rebooted, and now it works.  Here's hoping 5.0.1 comes soon and fixes this weird bug.

Answer (score -1):

Try resetting the screen lock on your phone. Worked for me. I have a nexus 4 too.

Comment: Have you tried this? This might've suited better as a comment